# Arquillian was remote jar not found

Tags: jboss-arquillian

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/arquillian/container/arquillian-was-remote-8.5/1.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT/arquillian-was-remote-8.5-1.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar

The above mentioned url is showing 404 error

Comment: Same problem here. The jar is not listed in the maven respository: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/arquillian/container/

Arquillian announced the release of the jar at the end of January 2015: http://arquillian.org/blog/2015/01/29/arquillian-container-was-1-0-0-Beta2/ As you can see in the comments, more people are having the same issue.

While fixing the dependency using the source can help, I don't think that this was the intended approach.

Any hint about where to find the jar is more than welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have to build it from sources. See here: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-was

Comment: Build failed with the current master. Following errors stack traces,
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/wasdev/wlp/maven/plugins/server/StartServerMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0